# How to filter a HashMap with a value Predicate?

Tags: java, filter, hashmap, java-stream

I have the following query header method:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> query(Predicate<String> valuePredicate)
```

Before this, I implementated another method with a specific column (label). It was:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> query(String keySelector,Predicate<String> valuePredicate) {
        try {
            final List<String> row = frameInfo.get(keySelector);
            List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(0, row.size()).filter(columnIndex -> valuePredicate.test(row.get(columnIndex))).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            Map<String, List<String>> auxMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : frameInfo.entrySet()) {
                for (int columnIndex : indices) {
                    auxMap.putIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>());
                    auxMap.get(entry.getKey()).add(entry.getValue().get(columnIndex));
                }
            }
            return auxMap;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
```

How could I implementate the new method with just 1 argument (valuePredicate)?

Comment: So you want a method that checks all columns and returns similar info in a map?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you could do it like so.  Since the predicate tests a string from a list which can be streamed, I don't see why you need to iterate the indices.

- Stream the `entrySet` from `frameInfo`
- then flatmap `e.getValue()` (a list)  and apply the predicate
- preserve the `key` and filtered `value` in a `String array`
- then group based on the key

```
public Map<String, List<String>> queryAll(Predicate<String> valuePredicate) {
    return frameInfo.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                    .filter(valuePredicate)
                    .map(s -> new String[] { e.getKey(), s }))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0],
                    Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1],
                            Collectors.toList())));
}
```

I'm tossing this one in as well, it's a rewrite of your existing method.

- it simply streams the list for the supplied key, applies the filter and populates the map.  Since there is only one key, you could just return a list.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> query(String keySelector,
        Predicate<String> valuePredicate) {
    return frameInfo.get(keySelector).stream()
            .filter(valuePredicate)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> keySelector));
}
```

If I misunderstood something, let me know and I will try to correct it.

Comment: In your original `query` method, you specify a key selector but you return the matches for multiple keys.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: You can also use `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(K, V)` or since Java 9 `Map.Entry(K, V)` instead of an array. Then you can replace `arr -> arr[0]` and `arr -> arr[1]` with `Map.Entry::getKey` and `Map.Entry::getValue`. Maybe a bit more readable.

Comment: I would have done that if the key and list types were different.   I actually  thought I was making it more readable by using a simple String array (since the types were the same).  LoL.

Comment: Comes down to personal preference I guess.

Comment: Hey WJS. Awesome solution but it goes wrong when I pass as parameter an Integer (cause not all Hashmap is Int), so then... I have the following call: df2.query(entry => entry.toInt > 60). How would you solve that? Thnx a lot, friend

Comment: How about passing the predicate as  `Predicate<String> validate = s->Integer.parseInt(s) > 60;`  This will throw an exception if the String is not an integer. 
 You could also modify your method signature to support different types but the predicate would have to match.